# Infinite loop in recursive code when traversing over JSON objects

Tags: javascript

I am getting a type error in this code and cannot find the reason!
Could anyone provide some explanation about the cause and how to get rid of it?
It is a hidden test case so I am unable to get a description or the test case itself:

The basic idea is the program recursively traverses teh object to compare the object values to the values given in the sesrch query and returns the relevant results

```js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
// Your code here!

let input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (chunk) {
    input += chunk;
});
process.stdin.on("end", function () {
    let data=[],count=0;
    let input_array = input.split("\n");
    for(let i=0;i<input_array.length;i++){
        if(input_array[i].length===0)continue;
        let op=input_array[i].split(' ')[0];
        if(op=="add")
            data.push(JSON.parse(input_array[i].split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')));
        else if(op=="get"){
            if(op)
            retrieve_data(input_array[i].split(' ').slice(1).join(' '));
        }
        else{
            data=delete_data(input_array[i].split(' ').slice(1).join(' '));
        }
    }

    function retrieve_data(query){
        let query_object=JSON.parse(query);
        let d=data.slice(0);
        if(query_object["type"]==="list"){
            let temp_arr=query_object["list"];
            d=d.filter(function(item){
                return item["type"]!==undefined && 
                temp_arr.every(function(val){
                    return item["list"].indexOf(val)>= 0; 
                });
            });
        }
        else{
            d=d.filter(function(item){
                let flag=filter_for_(query_object,item);
                return flag;
            });
        }
        for(let dat in d)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(d[dat]));
    }
    function filter_for_(qqq,iii){
        for(let q in qqq){
            if(typeof(qqq[q])=="object"){
                if(filter_for_(qqq[q],iii[q])===false){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(qqq[q]===null || qqq[q]===undefined || iii[q]!==qqq[q]){
                    return false;   
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    function delete_data(query){
        let query_object=JSON.parse(query);
        let d=data.slice(0);
        if(query_object["type"]=="list"){
            let temp_arr=query_object["list"];
            d=d.filter(function(item){
                return item.type===undefined && 
                temp_arr.every(function(val){
                    return item["list"].indexOf(val)>= 0; 
                });
            });
        }
        else{
            d=d.filter(function(item){
                let flag=filter_for_(query_object,item);
                return !flag;
            });
        }
        return d;
    }
});
```

> solution.js:55
>                   if(qqq[q]===null || qqq[q]===undefined || iii[q]!==qqq[q]){
>   TypeError:
>
> solution.js:50
>                   if(filter_for_(qqq[q],iii[q])===false){
>   TypeError:

Thanks!

UPDATE:::::Fixed the error now getting infinite loop; can anyone see the cause in this

Comment: Maybe `qqq` or `iii` is null? You've left out the relevant parts of the traceback, i.e. the message of the exception (what comes after `TypeError:`).

Comment: I do not get the message, its hidden because the test case is hidden...

Comment: iii might not be object in all paths, so it’s throwing a TypeError with the square brackets, iii[q]

Comment: Fixed the issue but now getting infinite loop:(